# I have npm i firebase toolse success and somthing error

Tags: reactjs, npm, google-cloud-firestore

**Error: Must select at least one feature. Use SPACEBAR to select features, or specify a feature by running firebase init [feature_name]**

Comment: add your command with parmeter, u need select one feature with `SPACE` key

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Select at least one feature with UP/DOWN/SPACEBAR key at this screen.